# Django - How to get only 2 object for a combination of fields with a queryset

Tags: database, django, api, content-type, django-queryset

If I have

```
Model.objects.all()
```

I want to get only one object for any content_object=foo, object_id=N.  How can I do that?  Say I am ordering by -datetime.  If I can get only one object in the queryset for any content_type=foo, object_id=N ... it should be the latest.. How to specify that I only want 1 object for any combination of content_object and object_id?

```
class CheckIn(models.Model):
    ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now=True)

    ...
    # This is the object that should be geocoded, hopefully
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

    class Meta:
        ordering=( '-datetime', )
```

Then to take a queryset:

```
checkins = CheckIn.objects.filter(
        datetime__gte=datetime.datetime.now() -
        datetime.timedelta(hours=24),
)
```

this can give me all of the checkins within the last 24 hours but I only want 1 object PER content_type=foo and object_id=N.

Comment: I think what you might be looking for is better distinct support, which is not currently available, but there's a patch for it:
http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6422

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to find latest *Model* object after some filtering? What do you mean by object id ? Is it a foreign key? Or it is the Model id auto generated by django? I guess it is the later. In that case, you can use just *id*. This may help you (I am assuming that you have at least these fields in your Model: content_object, dateField ):

```
Model.objects.filter(content_object=foo,id=N).order_by(dateField)[0]
```

**EDIT:**

I apologize. Well, the question was not *this* clear at the beginning (and I *am* a newb). Here is a naive approach (I think you want *distinct*):

```
d={}
[d.setdefault(str(a.content_type)+str(a.object_id),a) for a in checkins ]
d.values() # this gives your desired list of distinct objects
```

Comment: Add a check for length to this or it will blow up if it doesn't match any objects.

Comment: nice, this could indeed be the best answer for now. If there is any more efficient way (not bringing everything in memory/python_objects) it would be better. But, way to come back with a solution, thanks.